# Which connector type is used in practice in this case?

Tags: connector, cables

I'm planning to use STP twinax cable for diff. inputs to a data-acquisition board. The cable will look like this:

[image]

I don't want to use screw terminals and need something easy plug and play for others. I can make a connector board for the DAQ and add connectors to the cables.

But what connector type is used in practice for such pourpose? BNC connector would not work since it is for coaxial cables where the shield is one of the terminal.

Comment: What space and cost contraints?

Comment: Oh there is a tag called ""connector hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various different choices to select from to terminate your twinax cable. So a search engine query with "twinax connector" will turn up ideas for you. Here are basic available examples (some showing fittings as opposed to just cable ends):

[image]

[image]

[image]